# flutter : How To build a grid view with expanded text child

Tags: list, flutter, gridview

I need to Build this UI Using Flutter, `List or (Grid view)` of categories which every category has title as text and this texts is different lengths(maybe 4 letters and maybe 15 ).
any suggestions??
**Note : data will fetched from API endpoint**[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Wrap` instead of `GridView`.

```dart
Wrap(
  children: result
      .map(
        (e) => Chip(label: Text(e)),
      )
      .toList()),
```

More about [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) and [`Chip`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Chip-class.html).

Comment: Awesome, I Will try it then accept your answer, thanks